# Can not access application deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war, web-deployment

I have java application deployed to Tomcat 8.5 (it is shown in tomcat app manager). If I click on url that should open app, I have 404 error (not found anything under that url).

Same .war in same setup (exact tomcat directory) on different machine works.

All going on localhosts. What can be wrong, what should I look for?

Edit:

catalina logs:

```
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.830 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 14 2019 11:24:26 UTC
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.39.0
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\conf\logging.properties
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\temp
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.838 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:42.941 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.056 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.070 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.072 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 500 ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.39
18-Apr-2019 11:23:43.111 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\ProductResearch.war]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:46.783 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.070 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\ProductResearch.war] has finished in [3,959] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.072 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\docs]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\docs] has finished in [24] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\examples]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.432 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\examples] has finished in [336] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.433 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\host-manager]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.463 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [30] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.463 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\manager]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\manager] has finished in [27] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\ROOT]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.512 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [21] ms
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.517 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.525 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Apr-2019 11:23:47.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4455 ms
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: What should I look for? Answer: logs (catalina.out).

Comment: About permissions - everything is run from admin account. Is it not enought?

Comment: if the war was exploded (you then have a directory with the same name in `webapps` directory) check the `work` directory if it contains your application. It could be there was a previous version (remove the work/yourapp directory, redeploy it)

Comment: war was unpacked and I have directory with same name. Now, Catalina/localhost/directoryapp is empty (btw, directory work has only Catalina dir)

Comment: do you have a reverse proxy in front of your app? do you have a firewall? what is the url you access? try to stop tomcat, delete the exploded folder, delete temp files, delete work directory, and restart.

Comment: Nothing worked so far..  Only tomcat, no reverse proxy

Comment: Problems during the deployment usually give a SEVERE error. Do you have other logs ? When I had that kind of issues (long ago), the solution was to clean (stop the process, remove work , temp, webapp) and redeploy/restart. Be careful not loosing the context file (conf/Catalina/localhost/*.xml) during a hot redeployment.

Comment: Make sure that you have your Project's Context entry inside Host tag in your tomcat's server.xml (usually found at the end of the file). Just to be on safer side, remove all Context entries that are not used from your Host tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for input. We figured out what happend:

Application was front + backend. And during creating war, frontend was not properly built. On diffrent machine it must be casched. When we built frontend separately, site started working.

So it was not issue with Tomcat after all. We do not have any documentation so it is trial and error kind of thing.